# Does Deis support CRON like scheduling and how?

Tags: deis

I've been writing 100's of reports over the last few months. I have built a meta language that is used to schedule with fleet with service and timer unit files. These applications run from 10sec to 10min. Some are one-time and others repeat weekly, monthly, daily. Is there a Deis idiomatic way to implement that type of scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

Deis supports CRON semantics via the "clock process" model.  The general idea is that you create a long-running process that implements its own CRON, and you keep 1 running at all times with a `deis scale clock=1`.

For details see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes